# Got Warning : this linearlayout layout or its framelayout parent is possibly useless

Tags: android, warnings, android-linearlayout, android-framelayout

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

 // ---------------------------  Here I got warning  -------------------------
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/chat_list"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible" >
 // --------------------------------------------------------------------------
                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/white" >
                </ListView>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/text_entry"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/txt_inputText"
                        android:layout_width="125dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.8"
                        android:hint="@string/enter_text"
                        android:inputType="text" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_Send"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.2"
                        android:text="@string/send" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0" >
        </TabWidget>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

How to solve this warning ? I can't find any solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish, but you can get rid of the warning by moving `FrameLayout` content to a separate file and add it back to your `TabHost` by using `<include>` tag.

A possible version could look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <include layout="@layout/tab_chat_list" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

And tab_chat_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chat_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white" >
        </ListView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/text_entry"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_inputText"
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:hint="@string/enter_text"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_Send"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:text="@string/send" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

Hope this helps.

**Update**

*I noticed that some people are suggesting to remove `FrameLayout`. Although, that could have solved the problem in other cases, `TabHost` needs `TabWidget` and `FrameLayout` to function correctly.*

Answer (score 2):

The warning you are getting is this one:

> UselessParent
>
> Summary: Checks whether a parent layout can be removed.
>
> Priority: 2 / 10 Severity: Warning Category: Performance
>
> A layout with children that has no siblings, is not a scrollview or a
>   root layout, and does not have a background, can be removed and have
>   its children moved directly into the parent for a flatter and more
>   efficient layout hierarchy.

It can be turned off in Lint.

**Update:** I missed that tabhost requires a framelayout to work. Disabling the warning or going with shoe rat's solution should still fix the problem. (ignore paragraph below)

Assuming you don't need the FrameLayout (i.e. to add stuff dynamically), you can try removing it and adjusting the LinearLayout accordingly:

```
<LinearLayout
    ndroid:id="@+id/chat_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible" >
```

Comment: This is a good answer. It clearly explains the reason for the warning and the problem in your code, and offers a good answer (assuming you don't need the framelayout, which seems to be the case looking at your code).

Comment: @YekhezkelYovel, @Moberg: although this answer is theoretically sound, you should know that `TabHost` must contain a `FrameLayout` in order to work.

Comment: @shoerat I didn't know that. But than why use tab host at all? AFAIK it is not recommended for use anymore, tabs are supposed to be made using action bar. If you need to support old versions of the API ABS will do a much better and cleaner job than TabHost.

Comment: Anyway I believe a possible way to keep the FrameLayout in place and get rid of the warning could be to replace the LinearLayout with a scrollview. This will also guarantee visibility of all elements even on extremely small screens. But I didn't try it for this specific setting so I don't want to post an answer just yet.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llParent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/rlInner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Some Text" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

There is nothing wrong with it and any activity using this layout will run without a problem. But eclipse will give you a warning:

> This RelativeLayout layout or its LinearLayout parent is useless

As you can see, I only need one of the two container layouts above. Adding the RelativeLayout with id="rlInner" does nothing to change the layout. When eclipse finds a scenario like this, it gives you an appropriate warning to indicate the redundancy.

In your scenario, you can lose the FrameLayout altogether without disturbing the layout. And this would fix the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Add an ID to the parent linear layout.

It's useless because the parent linear layout doesn't have an id.  It means it would be difficult or impossible to add stuff in code outside the linear layout where you got the error.