# How to fix Android warning - FrameLayout layout or its LinearLayout parent is useless

Tags: android, layout, warnings

I have a warning in my Android project on a specific view.
What does it mean? How to fix it?

Warning on line 10: "FrameLayout"

*This FrameLayout layout or its LinearLayout parent is useless; transfer the background attribute to the other view
Android Lint Problem*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/stepLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/paper"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/example_image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/descExample" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonNext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/descButtonNext"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:src="@drawable/nav_next_40"
            android:text="@string/buttonNext" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonPrevious"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/descButtonPrevious"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:src="@drawable/nav_previous_40"
            android:text="@string/buttonPrevious" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonHome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/descButtonHome"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:src="@drawable/nav_home_40"
            android:text="@string/buttonHome" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonShare"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/descButtonShare"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:src="@drawable/nav_share_40"
            android:text="@string/buttonShare" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Dimitri, that means, you have declared all your attributes inside only FrameLayout, so there is no need of LinearLayout, your main LinearLayout is doing nothing, all things are doing FrameLayout, that's why you are getting that warning.

Comment: remove the LinearLayout and make FrameLayout as parent Layout.LinearLayout is for more than one Child Views.but for you it has only one child

Comment: Please, **simplify** your layout, for performances sake! Optimize by simplifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you **really** need the LinearLayout?

If not just move the android:background, xmlns:android and android:id to the FrameLayout and delete the LinearLayout and its closing tag. Also, from your code it doesn't look like you ever use the xmlns:ads in your code, so you can just delete that line too.

Keep things simple.

Answer (score 1):

Its just a warning. If you **absolutely** need those two layout's then you can ignore the warning. But it is a good practice to not ignore the warning and remove the unneeded layout. This warning hampers the **performance** of your app. Check this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080316/got-warning-this-linearlayout-layout-or-its-framelayout-parent-is-possibly-use?rq=1) for more information.